# a = 0.7f pero a < 0.7

Tags: java

¿Por qué una variable de tipo flotante con valor de 0.7... al someterla a la siguiente condición: (if a < 0.7)... esperando que si, si es menor, se imprima la palabra "si" y si no lo es, se imprima la palabra"no"?
La imagen excede los 2mb. Pero el resultado al correr el programa es "Si".

Codigo (java)

```
public comp ()
{
    float a = 0.7f;

    if (a < 0.7) 
          System.out.println("Si");
    else
          System.out.println("No");
}
```

Comment: Este tipo de titulos no son adecuados, te recomiendo leer lo siguiente y mejorar tu pregunta: [ask]

Comment: Aca necesitamos tu codigo como texto, no como imagen asi que no es una excusa el peso de la imagen.

Comment: Es importante la información que te proporciona eyllanesc, recuerda realizar un [mcve], saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java usa por defecto los numeros doubles para indicar valores reales, es decir:

- el 0.7 que usas en la comparacion es double.
- la variable `a` declarada es flotante.

Los numeros flotantes y doubles son implementadas usando el estandar IEEE 754, y tienen diferencias:

- float:  1bit para el signo, 8 bits para la exponente, y 23 para la mantisa = 32 bits.
- double: usa 1bit para el signo, 11 bits para la el exponente y 52 bits para la mantisa = 64 bits.

Por lo que ambos cometen errores, pero el error del flotante 0.7 es mayor que el del double 0.7.

Usando la siguiente [herramienta](https://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html) podemos ver:

float 0.7:

```
signo   exponente    mantisa
  0     01111110     1 .01100110011001100110011
valor real: 6.9999999e-1
```

double 0.7

```
signo  exponente    mantisa
0      01111111110  1 .0110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110
valor real: 7.0000000000000000e-1
```

Los valores reales son diferentes como se ven. el valor double es mayor al valor float por ese motivo el sì es impreso.

Referencias:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero una precisión.. no es que `Java use por defecto`; es el programa el que declara la variable `a` como de tipo `float`. Por defecto, Java solo compila y ejecuta el programa.

Comment: @SJuan76 yo no me refiero a la variable sino al 0.7 en el if: if (a < **0.7**)